# PHP foreach loop odd references behaviour

Tags: php, reference, foreach

I have a weird issue with a foreach loop and references.
Here is my code:

```
  $authors = array(                                                                                                                                                            
       new Author(array('first_name'=>'Name 1','last_name'=>'last name 1')),                                                                                                         
       new Author(array('first_name'=>'name 1','last_name'=>'last name 2')),                                                                                                   
  );                                                                                                                                                                           

  foreach($authors as $key => $author){                                                                                                                                                
    $authors[$key] = Author::manager()->getOrCreate($author);                                                                                                                       
    print $author->id."-".$authors[0]->id."<br>";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  }
```

So if we assume that both of those objects are created in the database, then the output shown is :

```
1-1
2-2
```

As you guess my question is: why does `$authors[0]->id` refers to `$author->id` ??
I suppose that it is a problem with reference but since I don't use reference in the foreach loop, I have no idea where it comes from!

Any suggestion will be welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the output isn't 1-1, 2-1? Looks like that'd be what it'd output. Just wanted to confirm?

Comment: Since you don't store any id's when you create the $authors array they will be set to 0, 1, .... So $authors[0] would be the same as $author in the first iteration.

Comment: @Ben No the output is definitely 1-1 2-2.

Answer (score 1):

> why does $authors[0]->id refers to $author->id ??

**It doesn't** (after the first iteration).

There's something wrong elsewhere (perhaps in `Author::__construct` or `Author::manager`):

```
class Author
{
    public $id;

    function __construct($params)
    {
        $this->id = substr($params['last_name'], -1);
    }
}


$authors = array(                                                                                                                                                            
    new Author(array('first_name'=>'Name 1','last_name'=>'last name 1')),                                                                                                         
    new Author(array('first_name'=>'name 1','last_name'=>'last name 2')),                                                                                                   
);                                                                                                                                                                           

foreach($authors as $key => $author){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    print $author->id."-".$authors[0]->id."<br>";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
}

/* 
output:

1-1
2-1

*/
```

Comment: Indeed, there is an ORM layer which execute the queries to create or get the data. Then I retrieved the PHP object model fed with the shadow data such as the id attribute.